# terraform to create EKS addon for vpc-cni; example of using configuration-values param to associate the IAM resources?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-eks

[Per the terraform documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/eks_addon#example-iam-role-for-eks-addon-vpc-cni-with-aws-managed-policy) for aws_eks_addon, I'm creating the resource, and then also creating additional iam resources ([also per their documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/eks_addon#example-iam-role-for-eks-addon-vpc-cni-with-aws-managed-policy)) for the vpc-cni addon. Everything works as far as the resource creation, and all resources are created without any errors. However, as is, the addon will not work properly, as the configuration is incomplete; it's missing the association with the IAM Role. The example does not show using the configuration_values parameter to associate the addon with the IAM Role resource being created in the example. In further research, it seems I need to query for what the configuration value keys are, but I'm not sure if I need to include all of them, and which ones are needed to get this working properly. Does anybody have an accurate example of accomplishing this? Following is my existing code:

```
resource "aws_eks_addon" "addons" {
  for_each                    = { for addon in var.addons : addon.name => addon }
  cluster_name                = data.terraform_remote_state.core.outputs.cluster_id
  addon_name                  = each.value.name
  addon_version               = each.value.version
  resolve_conflicts_on_create = "OVERWRITE"
  resolve_conflicts_on_update = "OVERWRITE"
}
    
variable "addons" {
  type = list(object({
    name    = string
    version = string
  }))
    
  default = [
    {
       name    = "kube-proxy"
       version = "v1.28.2-eksbuild.2"
    },
    {
       name    = "vpc-cni"
       version = "v1.15.3-eksbuild.1"
    },
    {
       name    = "coredns"
       version = "v1.10.1-eksbuild.5"
    },
    {
       name    = "aws-ebs-csi-driver"
       version = "v1.24.1-eksbuild.1"
    },
    {
       name    = "aws-efs-csi-driver"
       version = "v1.7.0-eksbuild.1"
    }
  ]
}
    
data "tls_certificate" "cluster_oidc_issuer_url" {
  url = data.terraform_remote_state.core.outputs.cluster_oidc_issuer_url
}
   
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "openid_connect_provider_assume_role_policy" {
  statement {
    actions = ["sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity"]
    effect  = "Allow"
    
    condition {
      test = "StringEquals"
      #   variable = "${replace(aws_iam_openid_connect_provider.openid_connect_provider.url, "https://", "")}:sub"
      variable = "${replace(data.terraform_remote_state.core.outputs.aws_iam_openid_connect_provider_extract_from_arn, "https://", "")}:sub"
      values   = ["system:serviceaccount:kube-system:aws-node"]
    }
    
    principals {
      identifiers = [data.terraform_remote_state.core.outputs.aws_iam_openid_connect_provider_arn]
       type        = "Federated"
    }
  }
}
    
resource "aws_iam_role" "vpc_cni_role" {
  assume_role_policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.openid_connect_provider_assume_role_policy.json
  name               = "${var.environment}-vpc-cni-role"
}
    
resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "vpc_cni_role_policy_attach" {
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEKS_CNI_Policy"
 role       = aws_iam_role.vpc_cni_role.name
}
```

**UPDATE**
My original conclusion as to the solution was incorrect. The required attribute is not, as I'd originally thought, in the configuration_values property, but rather the service_account_role_arn at the top level of the resource. It's still not displayed in the documentation example, but, the solution is to just set that attribute with the created IAM role arn. I went about utilizing terraform to better debug this, but first modifying the addon configuration in the aws console, and then running a terraform plan without making any changes, to see what terraform perceived as the necessary state change, and that highlighted the configuration attribute I was missing.

Comment: Are there any errors? Something that isn't working? If so, please add that to the question as well.

Comment: Everything is created without issue. The problem is it is not a complete configuration, so, the addon, while technically installed, will not function properly, as it's lacking the association with the iam role created for that purpose.